# If she beats him he'll claim she <cheated/has cheated>

Tags: tenses, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* by H&P (Page 126) has this example of **non-deictic past**:

> If she beats him he'll claim she *cheated*.

CaGEL explains this sentence as follows:

> The time of the (possible) cheating is not anterior to the time of my uttering [the sentence], but to the time of his (possibly) making a claim of cheating.

Can we change past *cheated* to present perfect *has cheated*?

> If she beats him he'll claim she *has cheated*.

Is there's any difference in meaning?

Comment: The second construction is a case of commentator's present perfect I'd say, even though there is a future frame of reference. In general I think there's difference in register and immediacy with this construction, but the basic meaning is the same. That seems to fit with http://www.putlearningfirst.com/language/15doms/football.html (intended for learners). It seems to me that with a reporting construction like this the immediacy is not so much expressed by the speaker as ascribed to the 'he' of the sentence.

Comment: I was about to say that they mean the same thing, but then I changed my mind.  I don't think any American would say "has cheated" in this context - we would always say "cheated," unless we really meant to suggest that someone cheated at some unspecified time in the past, perhaps before the game, in which case we'd add more clarifying language... "she's cheated[ before, and she did it again just now]."  The present perfect isn't a particularly favored tense in the US, though.  Answer might be different in the UK or elsewhere.

Comment: @cruthers In your more clarifying language, the full version looks like this: _If she beats him he'll claim she has cheated before, and that she did it again just now._ But how could you possibly use the present perfect to describe a past event that happened before another past event that is described by the past tense?

Comment: @JK2 I'm not sure I see the problem with doing so.  If I say to you "You've cheated before," I'm saying you're a known cheater who has cheated at some time in the past.  Pretty typical function of the present perfect.  If I continue, "... and you just cheated again - I just saw you slip a card out of your sleeve," I'm describing the more immediate and very recently occurring event, which is usually the job of the simple past tense in the US.  I'm not aware of any ban on present perfect preceding simple past.

Comment: @cruthers In spoken English, I'm sure no one would find fault with using the present perfect to refer to a past event that happened before another past event described in the past tense. But strictly speaking, the reference time of your cheating before is not the utterance time but the time of you just cheating again (a past time), so that the more correct form would be 'you'd cheated again' (the past perfect). The only context where the present perfect would be correct that I can think of is when you add "you just cheated again" as an afterthought, which I don't think is the case here.

Comment: @JK2 I assume you meant to say "you'd cheated before."  The day after the card game, it would be fine to say, "You'd cheated before, and you cheated again in that last game of ours."  But when the utterance is made right after the discovery of the cheating, no one would ever say "you'd" and, in fact, it would sound bizarre.  It must be that the time of the utterance is somehow lumped with the time of the cheating.  Not sure how this bears on the original question, though.

Comment: @cruthers You're right. I meant to say "you'd cheated before". And you're also right that this isn't quite helpful for the original question. More helpful would be the notion that, although the past tense can express **non-deictic past** in exceptional cases such as _she cheated_, the perfect tense in general expresses **non-deictic past** more readily.

Comment: There's no difference in meaning. However, American English speakers — unlike British English speakers — generally don't use the present perfect where the past simple will do. Put another way (from an AmE perspective), the second sentence is an awkward way of expressing the meaning of the first.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Do you find _Have you eaten already?_ awkward? (instead of _Did you eat already?_)

Comment: Somewhat. We would tend to say *Have you eaten yet?* and *Did you already eat?*

Comment: @TinfoilHat Let's say the lunch hour is between 1 and 2 pm, and it's 1:05. Which is better? _Have you eaten yet?_ or _Have you eaten already?_

Comment: *Have you eaten yet?* is more natural. I wish I could explain why — it's always a struggle to describe the perfect tenses, because for the native speaker, they "just happen." Also, we don't tend to end a sentence with *already*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Then, what if it's 12:30? Noticing the listener seems to have eaten 30 minutes before the lunch time, would you still prefer _Have you eaten yet?_ to _Have you eaten already?_? //Also, you've already admitted that BrE speakers prefer the present perfect, and they are also native speakers.// BTW, the examples are taken from Swan's Practical English Usage: Swan approves the sentences ending with _already_. So I don't know what your objection to ending with _already_ is all about.

Comment: *Already* at the end of a sentence tends to express a sort of surprise. So, yes, if you are surprised that your guest has already eaten lunch — a half hour ahead of schedule — then *already* at the end is appropriate.

Comment: @TinfoilHat I think the same logic should apply to the 1:05 scenario. When the lunchtime starts 1 o'clock and your colleague seems to have eaten their lunch at 1:05, you should be surprised, shouldn't you?